# How to create a limited access token for Kubernetes

Tags: authentication, kubernetes

I want to have a token that to use in a piece of code that has limited access to my k8s cluster and just be able to read the replicas of statefulsets and if required scale them, I don't want the person who uses that code be able to launch new stuff or delete running ones.
Is this possible? If yes how I can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [RBAC](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/) (Role Based Access Control) for this job.

Sample pod-reader role:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: pod-reader
rules:
- apiGroups: [""] # "" indicates the core API group
  resources: ["pods"]
  verbs: ["get", "watch", "list"]
```

Bind this role to a user:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
# This role binding allows "jane" to read pods in the "default" namespace.
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: read-pods
  namespace: default
subjects:
- kind: User
  name: jane # Name is case sensitive
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
roleRef:
  kind: Role #this must be Role or ClusterRole
  name: pod-reader # this must match the name of the Role or ClusterRole you wish to bind to
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

Change the `apiGroup` and `verbs` based on your requirements.